# PHP Form: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, php

This might be a lot of code I am sorry in advance. I am leaving work right now so I might not reply right away if someone has a solution or can run this locally and help me that would be great.

I've never done one of these form submissions with the backend PHP before (I'm usually just front end). I am getting this 400 bad request error that I'm not real sure what to do. I put the PHP separate from the snippet since there's no spot that I can see in the snippet to play PHP code.

My directory structure is this:

```
public(root):
 -(inside public) assets/js/mailer.js
 -(inside public) mailer.php
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").on('click', function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var institution = $('#institution').val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    $("#returnmessage").empty(); // To empty previous error/success message.
    // Checking for blank fields.
    if (name == '' || email == '' || phone == '' || institution == '' || message == '') {
      alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
    } else {
      // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
      $.post("../../mailer.php", {
          name1: name,
          email1: email,
          institution1: institution,
          contact1: phone,
          message1: message
        },
        function(data) {
          $("#returnmessage").append(data); // Append returned message to message paragraph.

          if (data == "Your message was received. We will contact you shortly.") {
            $("#ajax-contact")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
          }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php" class="mu-contact-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 input-field-name form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control scroll-left" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 input-field-email form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control scroll-right" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control scroll-bottom" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" name="phone" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control scroll-bottom" placeholder="Institution / Organization" id="institution" name="institution" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control scroll-bottom" placeholder="Message" id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <p id="returnmessage"></p>
  <input type="button" id="submit" class="submit scroll-top"><span>Submit</span></input>
</form>
```

Here its the PHP:

```
<?php
    // My modifications to mailer script from:
    // http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
    // Added input sanitizing to prevent injection

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);

        $institution = trim($_POST["institution"]);
        $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);


        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        // $cont_subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        $required = "This field is required"; 

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($institution) OR empty($phone) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo $required;
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "example@example.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New message from: $name ($email)";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Institution: $institution\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
        $email_content .= "Phone: $phone\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            echo "Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }
    } 
    else {
            echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

Comment: The only way your code is returning a 400 error is by entering on the `if`. Have you checked the variables to see which one is empty or if the email is a valid one? You can use `var_dump($variable)` to have the variable's content returned from the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code - see below. There where some problems with it, which I describe in detail in the comments. Just search for `@todo`, `@see` and `@link`.

I deliberately emptied the variable `$recipient` and commented the mail sending part at the end of "mailer.php". So, fill in the `$recipient`'s value and uncomment the mail sending part, in order to test.

I tried to change just the essential code parts.

P.S: The *headers* topic is not quite an easy one at first sight. So feel free to ask me anything and I'll do my best to explain it to you on the SO chat.

**public/index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <!-- CSS assets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/mailer.css">

        <!-- JS assets -->
        <!-- @todo Loaded needed js resources and mailer.js -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/mailer.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- @todo Added container. -->
        <div class="container">

            <!-- @todo Added header. -->
            <header>
                <h2>
                    Demo
                </h2>
            </header>

            <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php" class="mu-contact-form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 input-field-name form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control scroll-left" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 input-field-email form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control scroll-right" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control scroll-bottom" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" name="phone" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control scroll-bottom" placeholder="Institution / Organization" id="institution" name="institution" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control scroll-bottom" placeholder="Message" id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
                </div>

                <p id="returnmessage"></p>

                <!-- @todo Changed button bec. the "input" code was wrong - it didn't fire the onclick event. -->
                <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    <span>Submit</span>
                </button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**public/assets/js/mailer.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").on('click', function () {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var institution = $('#institution').val();
        var message = $("#message").val();

        $("#returnmessage").empty(); // To empty previous error/success message.

        // Checking for blank fields.
        if (name == '' || email == '' || phone == '' || institution == '' || message == '') {
            alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
        } else {
            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            /*
             * @todo Changed the path to "mailer.php" because the path must be relative
             * to the including page (here "index.php"), not to the included file (here "mailer.js").
             * @todo Changed "name1" to "name", etc, because see mailer.php @todos.
             * @todo Added the "fail" callback. Why? Because:
             * The page "mailer.php" throws a 420 (earlier 400) response header (from the "if" statement),
             * which is read by the browser and, based on its code (420), recognized as an error. So,
             * the browser activates the "fail" callback.
             * From the jQuery website: "If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code,
             * it will fail silently". So you must define a "fail" callback to handle the eventual errors.
             *
             * Note that, if the status code of the response is a custom one (420), defined by
             * the developer, then the corresponding error message is to be displayed.
             * Otherwise, e.g. if a system error occurres, the displayed message must
             * be a general, user-friendly one. So that no system-related infos will be shown to any user!
             *
             * Try to toggle between 420 and 400 in "mailer.php", in order to
             * see which error message is displayed in the "fail" callback.
             *
             * @link https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ jQuery.post().
             * @link https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ jQuery.ajax().
             */
            $.post("mailer.php", {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                institution: institution,
                contact: phone,
                message: message
            }, function (data) {
                //@todo Added this line. It adds a "success" class to the "returnmessage" container.
                $("#returnmessage").removeClass('error').addClass('success');

                $("#returnmessage").append(data); // Append returned message to message paragraph.

                $("#ajax-contact")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var message;

                if (jqXHR.status === 420) {
                    // The status code of the response is a custom one (420).
                    message = jqXHR.statusText;
                } else {
                    /*
                     * A system error occurred. E.g. the status code of the response is set by
                     * the system. For example a 400 code (described with the text "Bad Request").
                     */
                    message = 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again, or contact us.';
                }

                //@todo Added this line. It adds an "error" class to the "returnmessage" container.
                $("#returnmessage").removeClass('success').addClass('error');

                $("#returnmessage").append(message);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**public/assets/css/mailer.css:**

```
#returnmessage.error {
    color: #c00;
}

#returnmessage.success {
    color: #3adb76;
}
```

**public/mailer.php:**

```
<?php

// My modifications to mailer script from:
// http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
// Added input sanitizing to prevent injection
// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    /*
     * @todo This part activated a "400 bad Request" error because, for example,
     * you've sent "name1" from ajax, but here you are referencing the "name".
     * @see The comment marked with [*] bellow.
     */
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
    $name = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array(" ", " "), $name);

    $institution = trim($_POST["institution"]);

    //@todo Changed from "phone" to "contact", because "contact" were posted, not "phone".
    $phone = trim($_POST["contact"]);

    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    // $cont_subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    /*
     * @todo Try to use the logical operator "||" instead of "OR", "&&" instead of "AND", etc.
     * @link https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php Logical Operators.
     */
    if (
            empty($name) ||
            empty($institution) ||
            empty($phone) ||
            empty($message) ||
            !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
    ) {
        /*
         * @todo
         *
         * [*] This code triggered the 400 header because
         * the values posted by ajax were undefined.
         *
         * I changed to "header(...)" instead of "http_response_code(...)" + "echo ...".
         *
         * I changed 400 to 420 because 400 is a code
         * reserved by the system. See the rule bellow:
         *
         * This custom response header triggers the ajax error (see the "fail" callback in the js file)
         * because the status code begins with 4xx (which corresponds to the "client errors"). Here is
         * defined "420" as the custom status code. One can choose whatever code between 401-499 which
         * is not officially assigned, e.g. which is marked as "Unassigned" in the official
         * HTTP Status Code Registry. See the link.
         *
         * @link https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml HTTP Status Code Registry.
         */
        // Send a 420 custom response header (to the browser) and exit.
        header('HTTP/1.1 420 This field is required');
        exit();
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    /*
     * @todo Don't post sensible info on public websites!
     * I deleted the email address. Fill it on your system.
     */
    $recipient = "";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New message from: $name ($email)";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Institution: $institution\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
    $email_content .= "Phone: $phone\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    //@todo Uncomment only after assigning an email address to the "$recipient" variable.
    // $mailSent = mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers);

    /*
     * @todo You can toggle between TRUE and FALSE to test, then delete
     * this line after activating the line "$mailSent = ..." above.
     */
    $mailSent = TRUE;

    if ($mailSent) {
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        /*
         * @todo Here too: Throw a custom response header instead of just printing a text.
         * This way the header will be treated as error by the browser, which will manage
         * it with the "fail" callback of the ajax request.
         */
        // Send a 420 custom response header (to the browser) and exit.
        header('HTTP/1.1 420 Something went wrong and we could not send your message.');
        exit();
    }
} else {
    /*
     * @todo Here too: Throw a custom response header instead of just printing a text.
     * This way the header will be treated as error by the browser, which will manage
     * it with the "fail" callback of the ajax request.
     */
    // Send a 420 custom response header (to the browser) and exit.
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 There was a problem with your submission. Please try again.');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Wow you really went above and beyond with your answer. Well done.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Sorry, I sent you the previous two messages thinking that you have posted the question :-) Thank you for the appreciation!

Comment: Thank you, i will check this tomorrow when i get back into work. Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Thank you, I tested this morning. Took me a little bit to get it to work but I figured out what I was doing wrong with your code. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nick0989 You are welcome. I'm glad that I could help. Good luck!